# Trying to get a horizontally scrollable div to scroll automatically

Tags: angularjs, anchor-scroll

I have a horizontally scrolling div that is contained within a directive, where the directive is placed in a view. Upon adding elements to my scrollable div I want to always scroll to the end of the div. I am attempting to do this by placing an id on the element I want to scroll to, and setting $location.hash('myElementId'). I then call $scrollToAnchor().

I am seeing two problems. First, I haven't been able to make this work at all, and am wondering if $scrollToAnchor() works for horizontally scrollable areas. Second, calling $scrollToAnchor() seems to trigger the controller() function of my view to run again, along with all the controller() functions of any directive contained in the view, effectively causing everything on the view to redraw, which is not my intention.

Is there a way to cause scrolling to happen for a particular scrollable div only? Does $scrollToAnchor() cause a 'refresh' of the view by design?

Thanks